# How to migrate my 'Is Owner' Policy from v3 to Strapi v4

Tags: controller, strapi, koa, ctx

I used to have a **'Is Owner'** policy which worked like a charm. Since the new **Strapi v4** update it stopped working...

I highly think this code is outdated because it cannot find the function '**strapi.query**'..

```
module.exports = {
  async find(ctx) {
    const { user } = await ctx.state;
    const entities = strapi.query("connection").find({ links: user.id });
    return entities;
  },
}; // BIND LINK TO USER
```

also my **controllers/connections.js** which works below, **the problem is the code above!**

```
const { createCoreRouter } = require("@strapi/strapi").factories;

module.exports = createCoreRouter("api::connection.connection", {
  config: {
    create: {
      policies: [
        // pass a policy implementation directly
        (policyContext, config, { strapi }) => {
          policyContext.request.body.data.links = policyContext.state.user.id;
        },
      ],
    },
  },
});
```

How can i update my code so i will have the same function and fetch only the users todos.. ('**connection**' is my collection name & '**links**' is my *relation* to a user)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answered my own question with:**

*This lets you create a 'todo' and manage in a protected route (without other people seeing your posts)*

```
const { createCoreController } = require("@strapi/strapi").factories;

module.exports = createCoreController(
  "api::connection.connection",
  ({ strapi }) => ({
    async find(ctx) {
      const { user } = ctx.state;

      const entities = await strapi.db
        .query("api::connection.connection")
        .findMany({
          where: {
            links: user,
          },
          populate: true,
        });

      return entities;
    },
  })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
async find(ctx) {   
    const { id } = ctx.params;
    const { id: userId } = ctx.state.user;
    const entry = await strapi.db.query("api::YOURENTITY.YOURENTITY").findOne({
      where: { id, user: { id: userId } },
    });
    return entry
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.